# How to get data based on a value from Json with fetch by javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I'm trying to get the values based on the id of elements in HTML. How can I get it from the JSON array?
My JSON file looks like this:

```
[
  {
      "product": "gill",
      "link": "x.com",
      "thumbnail": "gill.jpg"
    },
    {
      "product": "folded",
      "link": "y.com",
      "thumbnail": "folded.jpg"
    }
]
```

and my JS file looks like:

```
window.onload = function (){
    const apiUri = "./test.json";
    const urun = document.getElementById("products");
    const search = document.getElementById("products").children[0].id;
        fetch(apiUri)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
            const Link = document.createElement("a");
            const Image = document.createElement("img");
                
            Link.setAttribute("href", data.link);
            Image.setAttribute("src", data.thumbnail);
            urun.append(Link);
            Link.append(Image);
            Link.classList.add(element.product);
        })
}
```

What I want to do is,
if const search = gill, get the thumbnail value of gill from JSON,
if const search = folded, get the thumbnail value of folded from JSON.

Could you please lead me the right way?

Comment: `window.onload = function` <-- **Don't do this**, instead use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { /* your stuff here */ })`. - this is because overwriting `window.onload` will silently _drop_ any previous event-handler - and anyway, `onload` is invoked for the `'load'` event which happens long after the HTML itself was ready for scripting - in fact the `'load'` event can occur _minutes_ after `'DOMContentLoaded'` if there's any slow-loading `iframes` or other extrnal content.

Comment: Maybe you want to first unserialize your JSON to work with the data as a naive JS object: Have a look at JSON.parse

Comment: @Psi [`response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) already does so.

Comment: @Psi do you mean to get data to js file? Actually i don't want to expose datas as much as possible. I'm a newbie in json world, trying to figure out. I saw an example which contains json.stringtify(data) and the data value was above like as const data = {  product : product }, i tought it is for searching in json but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @gmg Also, consider using `async function` and `await` with `try/catch` instead of `.then().catch()`.

Comment: @Ivar but it gives all data in json file, i want to get the values based on const search :/

Comment: @Dai are they instead of fetch? i saw an example on async function and await try to get json data but as i remember there were no fetch

Comment: Use `data.find(el => el.product === 'gill')`.

Comment: @Ivar, actually yes, that link you provided seems like the solution, only if i can figure out how to do this for data fetched from json file.

data.find(el => el.product === 'gill')
I will try this immediatly :)

Comment: @Ivar thank you so much bro, data.find method worked like a charm :))
You've made my day. 
I'm also new to stackoverflow, how can i tag it as solution answer?

Comment: why do you use fetch for importing data? it is a file that you have.

Comment: @gmg You should have the option to select "this answered my question" (or something similar) in regards to the post I linked earlier.

Comment: @DenizKaradağ to be honest i don't actually know :/
I was trying to achieve this and i found a similar project and i tried to edit that into my need. It's the first time i'm using json.

Comment: @Ivar as i googled how to mark it as accepted answer, i need to click on checkmark but only 2 answers with checkmark seem below. As these are comments, i don't have an option to click on checkmark.
I will try to copy your comment as an answer and mark it.

Comment: @gmg No need. We mark questions as [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) to keep all the relevant information in one place. You should have the option to accept the proposed duplicate at the top of your answer. That should be sufficient.

Comment: @Ivar i just saw it :) Done! 
Thank you so much again :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
let array = [
  {
      "product": "gill",
      "link": "x.com",
      "thumbnail": "gill.jpg"
    },
    {
      "product": "folded",
      "link": "y.com",
      "thumbnail": "folded.jpg"
    }
]

searchString = 'gill',
  searchRegExp = new RegExp(searchString , 'i'); // 'i' makes the RegExp ignore case

let result = array.filter(function(e){
    return searchRegExp.test(e.thumbnail);
}).map(function(e){
    return e.thumbnail; // Will return "['gill.jpg']"
});
```

Comment: I assume i can do it like;

let array = response.json;

And the rest of code as you provided, so it works? I'll try this solution as well

Comment: I just put the logic only, you can fetch the array from API response or from where ever you required.

Comment: i did not vote on your answer. Actually I haven't tried this method yet, since the find method worked. I will try this one also and i will inform about the result when i tried.